# unable to install module "Rasterio" using "pip"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, fedora, rasterio

I want to install "Rasterio" module for python3 in Fedora26. using "pip install raterio" I am getting an error "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1". moreover not able to download using "yum" and "dnf". Kindly solve the issue.

Comment: Weird. `pip install rasterio` usually works on Linux since they made [manylinux wheels](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/693) that include the relevant GDAL binaries.

Answer (score 0):

See [rasterio installation instructions](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio#installation). You need to install GDAL (and libraries required by GDAL).

You can try to install rasterio using [Anaconda](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/installation.rst#installing-with-anaconda).